# Make warning-message synonym of warning?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Both [warning](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warning) and [warning-message](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warning-message) are pretty low on questions, and both cover practically identical area. I don't have enough points (whatever they are) to propose synonym myself, so posting here.

Comment: I think warning should be merged with warning-message, it point only the warning message.

Comment: I don't think we really need this tag to begin with...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of making the two tags synonym, I have deleted them, since I agree with MPD.

I don't think we have users who answer questions about warning messages, and just to those questions. The fact then that some code is causing an warning message is not so relevant for answering to need its own tag.

Comment: Well, true enough :)